# Google maps error Uncaught InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to find out why my google map is not showing up. I did not create the original  code. What is causing the error and my google map to disappear?

```html
//XXXX: openInfoWindowHtml
/*--------------------------------------------------*/
/* GOOGLE MAP FUNCTIONS
/*--------------------------------------------------*/

var map, agentMarkers, reoMarkers, officeMarker, currentMarker, bounds, agentIcon, reoIcon, officeIcon;
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initAgentMap(lat, lng) {
 lat = isNaN(lat) || lat === null ? 37.4419 : lat;
 lng = isNaN(lng) || lat === null ? -122.1419 : lng;
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControlOptions : {
         style : google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
     }
 });
 agentMarkers = [];
 reoMarkers = [];
 currentMarker = null;
 bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

 var baseIcon = {
     size : new google.maps.Size(29,25),
     anchor : new google.maps.Point(15,25),
     imageMap : [0, 0, 22, 0, 22, 25, 0, 25]
 };

 agentIcon = {
     size : baseIcon.size,
     anchor : baseIcon.anchor,
     imageMap : baseIcon.imageMap,
     url : "/images/icon_redbook.png"
    };

 reoIcon = {
     size : baseIcon.size,
     anchor : baseIcon.anchor,
     imageMap : baseIcon.imageMap,
     url : "/images/icon_reo.png"
 };

 officeIcon = {
        size : baseIcon.size,
        anchor : baseIcon.anchor,
        imageMap : baseIcon.imageMap,
        url : "/images/icon_office.png"
 };
}

function plotAgent(lat, long, text, id) {
 var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position : point,
     icon : agentIcon,
     anchorPoint : new google.maps.Point(12,0),
     map : map
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
  infoWindow.setContent(text);
  infoWindow.open(map, marker);
 });
 agentMarkers[id] = marker;
 bounds.extend(point);
 return marker;
}

function plotREO(lat, long, text, id) {
 var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position : point,
     icon : reoIcon,
     anchorPoint : new google.maps.Point(12,0),
     map : map
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
  infoWindow.setContent(text);
  infoWindow.open(map, marker);
 });
 reoMarkers[id] = marker;
 bounds.extend(point);
 return marker;
}

function plotOffice(lat, long, text) {
 var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position : point,
     icon : officeIcon,
     anchorPoint : new google.maps.Point(12,0),
     map : map
 });
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function () {
  infoWindow.setContent(text);
  infoWindow.open(map, marker);
 });
 officeMarker = marker;
 bounds.extend(point);
 return marker;
}

function showAgent(id) {
 if(currentMarker != id){
  currentMarker = id;
  google.maps.event.trigger(agentMarkers[id], "click");
  map.setZoom(11);
  pnt = agentMarkers[id].getPosition();
  pnt2 = new google.maps.LatLng(pnt.lat() + .02 , pnt.lng());
  map.setCenter(pnt2);
 }

}

function showREO(id) {
 if(currentMarker != id){
  currentMarker = id;
  google.maps.event.trigger(reoMarkers[id], "click");
  map.setZoom(11);
  pnt = reoMarkers[id].getPosition();
  pnt2 = new google.maps.LatLng(pnt.lat() + .02 , pnt.lng());
  map.setCenter(pnt2);
 }
}

function showOffice() {
 if(currentMarker != 'office'){
  currentMarker = 'office';
  google.maps.event.trigger(officeMarker, "click");
  map.setZoom(11);
  pnt = officeMarker.getPosition();
  pnt2 = new google.maps.LatLng(pnt.lat() + .02 , pnt.lng());
  map.setCenter(pnt2);
 }
}
```

I'm trying to find out why my google map is not showing up. I did not create the original  code. What is causing the error and my google map to disappear?

Comment: It's hard to give an answer based on the given code(we don't know the arguments that will be used for the function-calls). Can you give a link to the page?

Comment: From the error message `Uncaught InvalidValueError: setPosition: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property lat: not a number`, you are passing invalid values in to a setPosition method somewhere. Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Here's a link to the page and http://reoredbook.thefivestar.com/find-an-agent/search-results/

Comment: A complete page is not a **minimal** complete example.

Answer (score 0):

You have provided some random javascript functions. To make a map you will need: 
1) to include google maps API.
2) to define a location for map on html page
2) define map size
3) initialize map, after Windows load event is complete.

For fun, I kept hacking your code until it gave some results. This may give you some hints of where you went astray . I strongly recommend reading API documentation and reproducing examples.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple

```
<html>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" type="text/javascript"></script>           


<style>
    /* we need to define map size */
    #map-canvas {        
        height: 350px;
        width: 600px;        
    }
</style>    
<script>

var map, agentMarkers, reoMarkers, officeMarker, currentMarker, bounds, agentIcon, reoIcon, officeIcon;
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

function initialize(){
    initAgentMap(37,-122)
    var marker = plotAgent(37, -122, 'hello world', 1);
    marker.setMap(map); }

function initAgentMap(lat, lng) {
    lat = isNaN(lat) || lat === null ? 37.4419 : lat;
    lng = isNaN(lng) || lat === null ? -122.1419 : lng;
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {  
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoomControlOptions : {
            style : google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    });
}

function plotAgent(lat, lng, text, id) {
    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position : point,
        title: text, // Appears on hover
        label: id, // Latter on marker      
    });
    return marker;
}

// don't start the process until Windows "load" event is completed
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue seems to be the URL of the maps-API, load the API from the correct URL (as defined in the documentation) :

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;key=AIzaSyDgNW8A9SvxtI0DazJOJ7x652I2BdhWxdg"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I resolved the issue. I updated the URL of the maps-API ( as defined in the documentation).